# How do I add "Android Project" to the File>New>_____ Menu in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I watch all of these Android tutorials online and am getting more and more into Android programming and I find it to be a slight hassle to have to go to File>New>Other>Android>Android Project every time, especially when the person I'm watching has it on theirs.

It would be very helpful if someone could provide me with a way for Android Project (and Android XML File) to be put on that "New" menu.

Thanks

Comment: its already there under new -> Android project.

Comment: just the same problem i m facing

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can add 'Android Project' to the 'New' menu (and customize others) as follows:

> Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective... > Tab 'Menu Visibility' > Expand 'File' > Expand 'New' > Tick 'Android Project'

Answer (score 1):

If your using eclipse in the toolbar the 8th icon is to Create New Project (its a folder with a a and a + sign sticking out the top of it).

[image]

Comment: It's not the 8th in mine, but I did manage to find it.  This is beneficial but not exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first one is new android project and the last one is new android xml file.

you can also customize what you want to add thru customize prespective by right clicking the menu area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have your eclipse configured properly? I think you need to install ADT and Android SDK first.

If you already have installed them, restart your eclipse to work with it properly.

If not and want to check how and where to install check [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

Following these instructions can enable all these things you want. Feel free to comment.

Comment: I can create Android projects fine, I just don't want to have to go through the "Other" folder to get to it, that's all.