# In Eclipse, there is no Android Project when I go to File->New-Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project

I have downloaded the Android SDK, set up the AVD and installed the necessary update for Eclipse. I think I have done everything, but when I try click on file -> New Project, I don't see an Android Project. There is an Android Folder and in it are things like: Android Application Project, Android Test Project, Android Sample Project etc. What do I do?

Comment: This is a common-enough problem. Before you reinstall Eclipse and the Android SDK, try resetting the "Java" perspective. In the upper-right of Eclipse, right-click the "Java' button and select "Reset".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent to 'Android Project' under Android in Eclipse > New > Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279051/equivalent-to-android-project-under-android-in-eclipse-new-project)

Answer (score 7):

[I've answered this questions before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257634/1029225). Basically you can just manually add the option, provided you do have the Android SDK installed of course:

> Window > Customize Perspective > Menu Visibility > Expand 'File' >
>   Expand 'New' > Tick 'Android Project'

Comment: It isn't even there. I've tried uninstalling Eclipse and the plugins.

Comment: @MH there is no Android Project for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes i try it :

```
Window > Customize Perspective > Menu Visibility > Expand 'File' > Expand 'New' > Tick 'Android Project' is Visible, if not available "Android Project" please First Install ADT Plugin Don't Forget ...
```

Here :
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html